# Interpretation of expected value

Tags: probability, expectation

Let $\mathbb{E}(X)$ be the expected value of a discrete random variable $X$. How do I interpret $\mathbb{E}(X)$?

One of the way to interpret $\mathbb{E}(X)$ is to consider a large number of trails of the experiment, and then take the arithmetic mean of the values taken by $X$. Equivalently, we can think of $\mathbb{E}(X)$ as the center of mass of the distribution of $X$. Are there any other better ways to interpret $\mathbb{E}(X)$ ?

For instance, if we have $X\sim\text{Geom}(p)$, interpreted as the number of Bernoulli trials needed to get one success, then we have $\mathbb{E}(X)=1/p$. If $p=1/10$, then we have $\mathbb{E}(X)=10$. This would mean that, on average it would take $10$ trials to get the first success. I am having a hard time to digest this!

Comment: Why do you have a hard time digesting that? You conduct an experiment where you toss a coin until you succeed, note the number of coin tosses in this trail. Repeat this experiment a large number of times and the average of all those numbers will approach 10.

Comment: @supreeth Do you know the meaning of life expectancy? That is also an expected value. Some people get older, some people die earlier, but on average, people die at some age, called life expectancy. I have a hard time NOT to digest this, because I can't imagine everybody to die at exactly that age...

Answer (score 1):

The ways you suggested are certainly correct. Another way to interpret $E(X)$ is as the value you would most often see if you were to observe $X$ over a long period of time.

Comment: I think you should be careful with involving time. The question is not about a random process. I suggest restating your interpretation as: "$E[X]$ is the value you would most often see if you were to observe the result of many realizations of $X$". However, this interpretation is flawed since the question is about discrete random variables. For example, consider a discrete random variable with values $0$ and $1$, which are assumed with probabilities $0.5$ and $0.5$, respectively. The expected value is $0\cdot 0.5 + 1\cdot 0.5 = 0.5$. This value cannot be realized.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sales (in units) of a product over 10 days:
\begin{array}{c|l|c}
\text{Sales} & \text{# of days, $f$} & \text{$rf$, $p$} \\
\hline
1 & \  \  \  \  \  \  \ \ \ 2 & 0.2 \\
2 & \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 5 & 0.5 \\
3 & \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 3 & 0.3 \\
\hline
 & \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 10 & 1 
\end{array}
The arithmetic mean and expected value of sales are equivalent:

$$\bar x=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^3 f_ix_i}{\sum_{i=1}^3 f_i}= \frac{f_1x_1+f_2x_2+f_3x_3}{\sum_{i=1}^3 f_i}=\frac{f_1}{\sum_{i=1}^3 f_i}x_1+\frac{f_2}{\sum_{i=1}^3 f_i}x_2+\frac{f_3}{\sum_{i=1}^3 f_i}x_3=$$
$$p_1x_1+p_2x_2+p_3x_3=\sum_{i=1}^3 p_ix_i=0.2\cdot1+0.5\cdot2+0.3\cdot3=2.1.$$

So, the sales on average are 2.1. Or it is expected to sell 2.1 products.